# Why do we say that in an impure semiconductors doped atoms can be treated as ions?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why is it that we say in an impure semiconductor when the doped atom(say a phosphorus in silicon material)loses electron then it can be treated as positive ion?It still has more number of electrons than number of protons associated with it.
Even if the bonding electrons just contributes to 1%(just to emphasize upon my point here)or even much less than that,still the net charge on the phosphorus atom must be negative.

Comment: It lost an electron. It is now trying to look like a silicon atom with four bonds to other silicon atoms. But it isn't a silicon atom - it has an extra proton, and thus has a net charge of +1. I'm really not sure how you get to any of the last two sentences.

Comment: Okay,I got your point.There was a misconception in my mind and your answer was very helpful sir. Thank you